# How to retrieve all rules of a quality profile using the web api?

Tags: sonarqube, salesforce, sonarqube-api

I have run a analysis on Sonarqube with Codescan.  The number of issues returned, is way above the 10000 web api limit.  Therefore, within my client/code I wanted to loop through all of the rules within a quality profile and return all the issues per rule.

How can I get a list of rules using the web api from java?

Comment: The 10000 web api limit, is with which web api exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`api/qualityprofiles/backup`](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/qualityprofiles/backup). It takes a quality profile key as parameter and returns an xml containing all "active rules".

Comment: Thank you @slartidan, i have implemented your suggestion and it works well.  Though i am also going to look into the below Massimo suggestion

Answer (score -2):

Newer SonarQube versions do not have the 10K issues limitation.
You have to loop n-times to collect all results.
For example:
Consider a project with 44K issues.
You have to discover first how many issues you have to read, call one time the /api/issues/search with only you project key and the parameter ps ( pagesize ) equal to 100
**http:///api/issues/search?componentKeys=&ps=100**

You could receive an answer like this

{"total":44130,"p":1,"ps":100,"paging":{"pageIndex":1,"pageSize":100,"total":44130},"issues":[{"key":"AVtoCSNP6OwvnmtEJjae","ru..........

So we have to claim 44130 issues, using a pagesize of 100 then you must call (44130 / 100 ) + 1 times the /api/issues/search for your project and for every request remember to increase by 1 the p ( page ) parameter ( so you can point the right portion of results )

Your sequence of command will be like this

**http:///api/issues/search?componentKeys=YOUR_PROJECT_KEY>&ps=100&p=1
http:///api/issues/search?componentKeys=YOUR_PROJECT_KEY>&ps=100&p=2
http:///api/issues/search?componentKeys=YOUR_PROJECT_KEY>&ps=100&p=3
....
http:///api/issues/search?componentKeys=YOUR_PROJECT_KEY>&ps=100&p=442**

Parse the result of every call and you will be obtained the list of your issues.

Cheers

Massimo

Comment: Thank you @Massimo Borgogno, i will give your suggestion a go

Comment: I have confirmed that SonarQube 6.3, released a few months before your post, and 6.5, released after your post, both have the 10k limit on /api/issues/search. If for some reason you know of a setting or workaround to remove this limit please let me know and I'll upvote you :-)